# Assembly location during run of unittest

Tags: unit-testing, resharper

I want my Assembly location, when the mstest runs, to be changed.
If I run my mstest unit tests using the visual studio, it runs in a subfolder of my project folder.
But if I run my mstest unit tests using resharper, the a call of this.GetType().Module.Assembly.Location says C:/temp/somewhere.

How can I change the resharper behavior? I tried already to change ReSharper -> Options -> Tools -> UnitTesting -> Run Tests from. But it did not take any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply un-check the `"Shadow-copy assemblies being tested"`.
Tests will run from your selected location in the `"Run tests from"` option.